# The proof of a Sobolev embedding inequality by a compactness argument

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I want to prove the following

If $N\ge 3$ there exists a constant $c_0=c_0(\Omega)$ such that for all $\alpha\ge 1$ and $z\in H^1(\Omega)$
        \begin{align}
   \left(\int_{\Omega}|z|^{2^*}\right)^{\frac{2}{2^*}}&\le c_0\left(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla z|^2\,dx+\left(\frac{2}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}|z|^{2/\alpha}dx\right)^{\alpha}\right),
  \end{align}
        with $2^*:=\frac{2N}{N-2}$.

**Proof**:
(i) Let us prove by contradition. Suppose for all $\lambda>0$ there exists $z\in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\alpha\ge 1$ such that 
\begin{align*}\tag{A.1}
 \left(\int_{\Omega}|z|^{2^*}\right)^{\frac{2}{2^*}}>\lambda\left(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla z|^2+\left(\frac{2}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}|z|^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\right)^{\alpha}\right)
\end{align*}
We define a sequence $\{\lambda_n\}$ such that $\lambda_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. It follows from (A.1) that these exist $z_n\in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\alpha_n\ge 1$ such that
\begin{align*}\tag{A.2}
 \left(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla z_n|^{2^*}\right)^{\frac{2}{2*}}>\lambda_n\left(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla z_n|^{2}+\left(\frac{2}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}|z_n|^{\frac{2}{\alpha_n}}\right)^{\alpha_n}\right)
\end{align*}
which implies in particular that $z_n\ne 0$. We divide inequality (A.2) by $\|z_n\|_{L^{2^*}(\Omega)}^2$ to obtain
\begin{align*}\tag{A.3}
 \int_{\Omega}\left|\nabla\frac{z_n}{\|z_n\|_{L^{2^*}(\Omega)}}\right|^2+\left(\frac{2}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}\left|\nabla\frac{z_n}{\|z_n\|_{L^{2^*}(\Omega)}}\right|^{2/\alpha_n}\right)^{\alpha_n}<\frac{1}{\lambda_n}
\end{align*}
Setting 
\begin{equation*}
 w_n=\frac{z_n}{\|z_n\|_{L^{2^*}(\Omega)}},
\end{equation*}
We deduce that
\begin{align*}\tag{A.4}
 \int_{\Omega}\left|\nabla w_n\right|^2+\left(\frac{2}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}|w_n|^{2/\alpha_n}\right)^{\alpha_n}<\frac{1}{\lambda_n}
\end{align*}
It follows from ($A.3$) and ($A.4$) that

\begin{align*}\tag{A.5}
 \|w_n\|_{L^{2^*}(\Omega)}&=1\qquad (a)\\
 \|\nabla w_n\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}&\to 0\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty\quad (b)
\end{align*}

so that in particular there exists $w\in H^1(\Omega)$ such that as $n\to\infty$, $w_n\rightharpoonup w$ weakly in $H^1(\Omega)$ and $w_n\to w$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$ along a subsequence. It also follows from (A.5) and the weak lower semicontinuity of $z\mapsto\int_{\Omega}|\nabla z|^2$ that $\nabla w=0$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. Thus there exists a constant $l$ such that $w=l$ and $w_n\to l$ strongly in $H^1(\Omega)$. Since the embedding from $H^1(\Omega)$ into $L^{2^*}(\Omega)$ is continuous we have that
\begin{equation}
 w_n\to l\quad\text{strongly in }L^{2^*}(\Omega)\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to\infty
\end{equation}
and therefore it follows from (A.5) that
\begin{equation}
 |l|=|\Omega|^{-1/2^*}
\end{equation}
and we may suppose that $l>0$. Furthermore, one could also deduce from (A.4) that
\begin{align}
 \left(\frac{2}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}|w_n|^{2/\alpha_n}\,dx\right)^{\alpha_n}\to 0\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty
\end{align}

---

---

Now, here is where I confuses about
1. 
"
It also follows from (A.5) and the weak lower semicontinuity of $z\mapsto\int_{\Omega}|\nabla z|^2$ that $\nabla w=0$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. Thus there exists a constant $l$ such that $w=l$ and $w_n\to l$ strongly in $H^1(\Omega)$. "

What results from functional analysis do I need to conclude the existence of this $l$? Then what is the reference I can look up?

2. How does (A.5) leads to 
   $$|l|=|\Omega|^{-1/2^*}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b). 
Since $\lambda_n \to +\infty$, we have $\frac{1}{\lambda_n} \to 0$. Hence, from (A.4) and due to the fact that 
$$
\frac{2}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}|w_n|^{2/\alpha_n} \geq 0,
$$
we get
$$
0 \leq \int_{\Omega}\left|\nabla w_n\right|^2 \leq \int_{\Omega}\left|\nabla w_n\right|^2+\left(\frac{2}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}|w_n|^{2/\alpha_n}\right)^{\alpha_n}<\frac{1}{\lambda_n} \to 0.
$$
Thus, 
$$
||\nabla w_n||_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 = \int_{\Omega}\left|\nabla w_n\right|^2 < \frac{1}{\lambda_n} \to 0
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @math101 $|\nabla w_n| \geq 0$ by definition of absolute value (or Euclidean norm if we are in $\mathbb{R}^n, n > 1$). Therefore, integral of it will be also nonnegative.

Comment: thx for that, i deleted the silly question asked.